# Can't create EF Core migrations table; how to correctly initialize SQL Server schema, database and user using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I am trying to run the very first migration using EF Core but I am getting an error:

> Failed executing DbCommand (42ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> IF SCHEMA_ID(N'***') IS NULL EXEC(N'CREATE SCHEMA [***];');
> CREATE TABLE [***].[Migrations] (
> [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
> [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
> CONSTRAINT [PK_Migrations] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
> );

But when I connect to the database as `sa` and run

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO ***
```

I get the error

> Cannot find the user '***', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

I suppose the way I created schema, database and user/login isn't correct. The database has been initialized by running these two scripts:

```
USE master

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = N'$(Schema)')
BEGIN
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE SCHEMA [$(Schema)] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'$(Name)')
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE $(Name)
END

----------

USE $(Name)

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT principal_id FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = '$(Login)') 
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN $(Login) 
    WITH PASSWORD = '$(Password)'
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT principal_id FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = '$(User)') 
BEGIN
    CREATE USER $(User) FOR LOGIN $(Login)
END
```

I am using `go-sqlcmd` to run the scripts and for some reason I have to split the commands in two scripts, otherwise not all the objects are created. Both scripts execute without errors and I can see the database, the user and connect to the database using the created login and password but EF can't create the migrations table.

**UPDATE**: now the schema is correctly created in the application database.

Run:

```
USE {Database}

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO {User}
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: [{Schema}] TO {User}
```

Returns error:

> The specified schema name "{Schema}" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

But I can access the database via Azure Data Studio using the created user and I see the new created schema.

Comment: Why does your script start by creating a schema in `master`?

Comment: As for the error, I would suggest it's telling you the problem and the `USER` does *not* exist in the database you are connected to. I would check that the `USER` has been created and/or that you have spelt the `USER`'s name correctly.

Comment: About the schema creation, that was a mistake. I moved the statement in the other script so it runs in the application database. Regarding the user, you are right. I was granting the permissions in `master` where the user doesn't exist. I add an update to the question, after running `GRANT` it says that the user doesn't have permissions for the schema. Did I granted permissions correctly?

Comment: It's unclear whether you still have a question.

Comment: Yes, I still do. Database, schema, login and user are all created but when EF tries to create the migrations table I get an error `The specified schema name "***" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it` but when I connect to the database with the new login I see the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by replacing the two `GRANT` statements with

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [$(User)]
```

The idea at the beginning was to give the user the least permissions possible necessary to just do its job, I don't know if making it database owner is a good practice but for the moment it fixes the error.